# CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost fails to connect to server while mobile safari can

Tags: ios, networking, proxy, websocket, socketrocket

I have a websocket enabled webapp and I use SocketRocket to work with it from my iOS app. Everything was fine until I changed network settings on iPad to work without DNS and thru proxy. Now I cannot connect to my web app via iOS app although I can connect to it via mobile safari.

I use wss scheme and self signed certificates. 
Both DNS host name "example.net" or ip 10.10.1.1 do not work. I receive error NSPOSIXErrorDomain 64 "Host is down" or NSPOSIXErrorDomain 60 "Operation timed out".

I would appreciate any ideas why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging into SocketRocket code it appears that they do not support connections thru proxy.

I was getting NSPOSIXErrorDomain 64 "Host is down" or NSPOSIXErrorDomain 60 "Operation timed out" because obviously I can't reach needed host directly.

Comment: @madlymad There is no workaround. You can just grab forks of SocketRocket or PocketSocket libraries which have this implemented https://github.com/strukturag/PocketSocket

Comment: Yes it's been a while that a user made a push commit about HTTP proxy support in SocketRocket.

Comment: Well I use that library for quite some time and it is proven to be stable. It should not be that hard to merge with upstream if you really need it though.